# Visual Studio Code Cosmos DB extension, viewSettings file location

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-cosmosdb

With the Visual Studio Code Cosmos DB extension, where do you locate the cosmosDB.graph.viewSettings file for the viewer settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the official doc: [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). Open the user settings as below:

> On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
>
> On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings

Then you could find the `cosmosDB.graph.viewSettings`

[image]

Hope it helps you.